# How to set layout and views to specific controller in grails

Tags: grails

In simple the Grails application, I have created the controller and the corresponding GSP view page. I have also created the layout file and I want to bind it to the view. How to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to direct the corresponding view to use it. You can do this by adding the following to your view's html-head:

```
<meta name="layout" content="$yourlayout" />
```

Or by adding this to your controller class:

```
static layout = '$yourlayout'
```

In both ways, substitute $yourlayout with the name of your layout file (without the .gsp-extension).

There are also other ways to trigger a layout e.g. by convention, you can find all of them in  the [Grails user guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#layouts).